# Creating a Cocoa Framework & using it from another Cocoa project

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks, settings

OK, I know this question seems pretty easy to answer, or maybe documented, but I'm honestly 100% confused around the subject, with effects as... silly as submitting an application for review by Apple and then realizing (by the logs they sent me back), that the Framework wasn't there (actually, it was... but my Cocoa app was looking for it elsewhere).

Ok, so... let's say I have a framework with like 100 different classes I mostly use (which I do have), what settings should I use if I want to **"bundle" my Framework with my apps** (and copy it in the framework folder of the app bundle)?

- Build Settings -> Installation Directory? (of the Framework)
- Build Settings -> Header Search Paths? (of the App)
- Build Settings -> Library Search Paths? (of the App)
- Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths? (of the App)
- use @rpath? and how?
- anything else?

Given that I mostly have issues **"linking" my frameworks to my apps** (the framework compiles great, but there may be a **runtime error** occasionally when the app using it tries to run (which I... occasionally manage to solve - but without actually knowing how... lol)), **what would you suggest?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third party frameworks should be included with the app in a Frameworks directory of the app bundle.

Add a new copy files build phase and specify the Frameworks directory, then add your frameworks to this directory:

[image]

You may also need to tell Xcode where the frameworks are by adding a `Framework Search Path` like `"$(SRCROOT)/MyFrameworks"`.